# I got an error in my stored procedure at DECLARE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I learn to use stored procedure for insert, but I get this error

> incorrect syntax near DECLARE

I don't understand much about syntax, please help to correct it and explain it for me too;

```
USE P_DETAIL

CREATE PROCEDURE PRO_INSERT DECLARE 
@ST_ID int,
@ST_NAME NVARCHAR(50),
@ST_SEX NVARCHAR(10),
@ST_DOB DATE,
@ST_AGE INT,
@ST_POSITION NVARCHAR(30),
@ST_ADDRESS NVARCHAR(60),
@ST_PHONE INT,
@SV_ID INT,
BEGIN

INSERT INTO TBL_STAFF
(
ST_ID ,
ST_NAME ,
ST_SEX ,
ST_DOB ,
ST_AGE ,
ST_POSITION ,
ST_ADDRESS ,
ST_PHONE ,
SV_ID 
)
VALUES
(
@ST_ID ,
@ST_NAME ,
@ST_SEX ,
@ST_DOB ,
@ST_AGE ,
@ST_POSITION ,
@ST_ADDRESS ,
@ST_PHONE ,
@SV_ID 
)

END;
```

Comment: It's a **stored procedure** - a procedure that is **stored** inside SQL Server. It has really nothing to do with a "store"

Comment: Maybe next time you should **check the documentation** before posting here..... [this is the topic in SQL Server Books Online on procedures](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line `CREATE PROCEDURE PRO_INSERT DECLARE` to `CREATE PROCEDURE PRO_INSERT AS`. Then declare each variable, like this:

```
USE P_DETAIL

CREATE PROCEDURE PRO_INSERT 
AS
DECLARE
... --List of variables and procedure code
```

One more thing - you need to remove the comma after `@SV_ID INT,` since that is the last parameter in your input parameters list.

Check out this [sample Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0649a) to see where your code is going wrong.

Comment: ok i founnd it, it work sorry for last commend , it my mistake `@SV_ID INT,`